# Best way to obtain objects from a collection that can be cast to a specific type using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to obtain all the Point objects in the a more general collection of Entities using Linq.  Please refer to the comments in the code below.  It appears that .Cast() and .OfType() do not seem to do what I need.  Is the code below the best option?

```
// IHost has an Entities collection that contains different types of entities that implement IEntity, and one of specific types may be a Point object.
    public System.Linq.ParallelQuery<Point> GetPoints(IHost entityHost)
    {
        // Is this the best way to get a collection of Points from the Entities, using Linq?
        // I believe Entities.OfType<Point> does not work because the type of item in Entities is IEntity
        // I believe Entities.Cast<Point> does not work because there will be exceptions due to non-Point objects in the collection
        return entityHost.Entities.Where(o => o is Point).Cast<Point>();
    }
```

Comment: `OfType` will work if the type inside can be successfully cast to the type you are after. Did you actually try it? Says it right there in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`OfType` combines those two operations:

```
 return entityHost.Entities.OfType<Point>()
```

> I believe `Entities.OfType<Point>` does not work because the type of item in `Entities` is `IEntity`

No, that's the *declared* type of `Entities`.  `OfType` looks at the *actual* type of each item, and adds it to the result if it "is" a `Point`.  By "is" I mean "can be cast to" - literally [using the `is` operator](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/System.Core/R/d25cf953c577dcd6.html):

```
static IEnumerable<TResult> OfTypeIterator<TResult>(IEnumerable source)      
{
    foreach (object obj in source) {
        if (obj is TResult) yield return (TResult)obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast responses.  By understanding that OfType *should* work (and why), I was able to locate the actual problem.  It works now!  Thanks again!